# Magento 2 Custom template content will not shown in graphql response of CMS page

Tags: magento2, template, cms-pages, graphql

I have a CMS page in which I want to show the date e.i Current date OR Date after 5 days etc. So for that I have created a template file and call inside the CMS page.
It will show content in Front but in GraphQl response, it will not available.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7156601?key=f19c0b7a0aebdc1fe91ef37c79085e5a
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7156679?key=66c833a0c044b5e7738b4efd6c6fc565
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7156696?key=e448522e6ef5d584d19e2c396cef11c1
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/7157210?key=ac2f2a2d431ee1cadb762e46184d4a44

**graphQl Request(Query)**:

```
{
        cmsPage(identifier: "home") {
        url_key
        title
        content
        content_heading
        page_layout
        meta_title
        meta_description
        meta_keywords
      }
    }
```

**Current Response**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "cmsPage": {
      "url_key": "home",
      "title": "Home Page",
      "content": "<p>Hi, DD/MM/YYYY ''</p>\r\n<p><img src=\"http://m242.com/media/wysiwyg/images.jpeg\" alt=\"\"></p>",
      "content_heading": "Home Page",
      "page_layout": "1column",
      "meta_title": "",
      "meta_description": "",
      "meta_keywords": ""
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Response**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "cmsPage": {
      "url_key": "home",
      "title": "Home Page",
      "content": "<p>Hi, DD/MM/YYYY 'Today is 04/08/2021'</p>\r\n<p><img src=\"http://m242.com/media/wysiwyg/images.jpeg\" alt=\"\"></p>",
      "content_heading": "Home Page",
      "page_layout": "1column",
      "meta_title": "",
      "meta_description": "",
      "meta_keywords": ""
    }
  }
}
```

**CMS page Content**:

```
<p>Hi, DD/MM/YYYY '{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::current_date.phtml"}}'</p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/images.jpeg"}}" alt=""></p>
```

**Template file(/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/current_date.phtml):**

```
<?php
    echo "Today is " . date("m/d/Y") . "<be>";
?>
```

Do I need to create a resolver?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an **area** issue (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html).

Because you make the request through graphql magento looks for a template file in your module in the **graphql area**:

```
Vendor/Module/view/graphql/templates
```

If it can't find this file it can also throw an '*Error filtering template: Invalid template file*' error.

You can solve this by creating the file template

```
Vendor/Module/view/graphql/templates/current_date.phtml
```

Or

```
Vendor/Module/view/base/templates/current_date.phtml
```